# how can i return all user information for each post (articles) in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have an app where users upload articles and an image but as I view articles, I can't view user names for all users, I only view for the active account.

**articles model (relationship)**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class)->select(['id', 'name']);
}
```

**user model (relationship)**

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Article::class);
}
```

**article controller**

```
public function showToReporter()
{
    $articles = Article::with('user')->get();

    return view('articles.articles')->with('articles', $articles); 
}
```

my db schema
user->id, name
articles->id,user_id, title, body

blade template

```
 @foreach ($articles as $article)
                              <tr>
                                <td>{{ $article->user }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $article->title }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $article->school_name }}</td>
                                <td><img src="{{ asset('storage/image_uploads/' .$article->image_upload) }}" alt="image" width="80px;" height="80px;"></td>
                                <td style="display: flex;">
                                  <a href="/articles/{{ $article->id }}/download" class="btn btn-secondary float-left">Download</a>
                                    <a href="/articles/{{ $article->id }}/edit" class="btn btn-primary float-left">Edit</a>

                                    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/articles/{{ $article->id }}/forward" method="POST" style="">
                                      @csrf
                                
                                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning float-left">Foward</button>
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              @endforeach
```

[image: this is my frontend screenshot]

Comment: please show your db schema for this

Comment: @foreach ($articles as $article)
                              <tr>
                                <td>{{ $article->user }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $article->title }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $article->school_name }}</td>

Comment: my db schema .......user->id, name.....article->id, user_id, title,body

Comment: do all these 'articles' actually have a `user_id` set?

Comment: yes they do @lagbox

Comment: do these 'id's relate to ids in the 'users' table? it would seem not, unless there is some odd global scope being applied to User or something ... and what does the "active account" mean?